# Avoid writing duplicates using parse.com?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Now, I did a check on the validity of the e-mail address:
app.js

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

  app.set('views', 'cloud/views'); 
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  
  app.use(express.bodyParser());

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
var Email = Parse.Object.extend("UserEmail");
var email = new Email({ email: req.body.EMAIL });
var temp =req.body.EMAIL;
if (temp.match(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i)){
    email.save().then(function(email) {
        res.render('home', { message: '1' });
        }, function(email) {
            res.send('Oops, something went wrong!');
            });}
   else{res.render('home', { message: '2' });}
});

app.listen();
```

But the problem is that there is a possibility to write again the same address, but that if such an address exists, then display a message on the page:
If not hard-explain how to add validation?

Comment: if you don't have a database, then this is going to be very difficult.

Comment: I have a database and have a record of email, I can not understand - how to check existing entries!

Comment: That code should be server side, you won't be checking it in Javascript. (You can AJAX the information, but that's not the proper solution, you shouldn't be bringing a list of user emails client side, that's a huge security/information exploit)

Comment: This is handled in the cloud, not on the client side. Do you know about cloud code and Parse(dot)com javascript?